# How to get @media(max-width 425px) to work alone, and not follow @media(max-width 768px)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want to make responsive page using react JS. I have some problems making it. I don't really know how media query CSS works, but for `@media(max-width:1024)` and `@media(max-width:768px)` sizes it works as I expected.
I guess for size `@media (max-width:425px)` will also work as where `@media(max-width:768px)` works. But apparently starting from `@media(max-width:425px)` it follows the previous breakpoint(`@media(max-width:768px)`) and `@media(max-width:375px)` following the `@media(max-width:425px)` style. At breakpoint 320px back to my expectations.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        This is content
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
.container{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media(max-width:1024px){
    .container{
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
@media(max-width:768px){
    .container{
        background-color: green;
    }
}
@media(max-width:425px){
    .container{
        background-color: blue;
    }
}
@media(max-width:375px){
    .container{
        background-color: rosybrown;
    }
}
@media(max-width:320px){
    .container{
        background-color: rosybrown;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for each breakpoint to take its own style. As in `max-width:1024px` which takes a yellow background and `max-width:768px` takes a green background. Is it possible if I want if at `max-width:425px` it takes a blue background and at `max-width:375` it takes a rosybrown color. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: The code you posted here should work as expected. Check for typos, non-closed or superfluous brackets and similar things

Comment: @Spectric Really sir? even if we reset responsive 425px on chrome it will take blue background?

Comment: @Johannes I checked, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the only screen

```css
@media(only screen and max-width:768px){
    .container{
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is show error unexpected

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
 Try the code above, then change to screen size less than 600px to see if the color will change